# Grid/Flexbox layout with fitting dynamic width and height elements

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-grid

I try to create a grid with one central element like at image using `flexbox`. `f` square has class `active` where I double width and height. is this possible to make other squares fit to the rest? Sholud I use 
 `flexbox` or maybe `grid`?

Next I want to add listener with `click` event. Clicking on square will move it to central position and add `active` class and add transition on this move (it can't be done with `gird`??)

[image: correct grid].

Here is my pen: [link](https://codepen.io/pawell67/pen/QaXpwv)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout-but-with-elements-ordered-horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this layout you can use CSS Grid layout. You can set `repeat(4, 100px)` on both grid-template columns and rows. For **active** box you can use `2 / 4` on `grid-row` and `grid-column` so that box with class active will always be in the middle of layout. For spacing you can use `grid-gap`

```js
$(".wrapper .box").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.box {
  background: #444444;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box:not(.active):hover {
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in;
  background: orange;
}
.active {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">a</div>
  <div class="box b">b</div>
  <div class="box c">c</div>
  <div class="box d">d</div>
  <div class="box e">e</div>
  <div class="box f active">f</div>
  <div class="box g">g</div>
  <div class="box h">h</div>
  <div class="box i">i</div>
  <div class="box i">j</div>
  <div class="box i">k</div>
  <div class="box i">l</div>
  <div class="box i">m</div>
</div>
```